# Graph API failure in fetching sites

Tags: azure, sharepoint, graph, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I had a graph app created on Azure and it was running fine, the secret just expired so i created a new one. Now im not able to fetch sites using graph API with the following error:

```
 errorcode: AccessDenied, message: Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.
```

Nothing has changed in terms of permissions, i confirmed my App has both Application and Delegate permissions
[image: PERMISSIONS]

The only thing changed is i created a new secret and now using that, what could be the issue

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error ***"AccessDenied, Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token"*** usually occurs if the access token doesn't contain any scope or claims to perform the action.

> **Note** that: If you are using Client Credential flow, then grant application API permissions. If you are using interactive flow, then make use of delegated API permissions to generate the access token.

I created an Azure AD application and granted API permissions same as you:

[image]

Generated **access token using Client credential flow** by using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:client_credentials
```

[image]

***Make sure to decode the access token in [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/) and check if the roles or scopes are present:***

[image]

By using the above access token, **I am able to fetch the sites successfully**:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites
```

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, check the below:

- Make sure to grant admin consent to the API permissions.
- Make sure that the roles or scopes are present in the access token by decoding it.
- Creating a new secret and passing it to generate access token is normal and doesn't cause an error.
- Try generating the access token again and check.
- Make sure the access token is not expired.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: I was using the token generated by REST to query the graph API which wasn't working.